# Как в языке С записать "Xn"?

Tags: численные-методы

Как в языке С записать "Xn" для формулы касательных, что бы Х было неизвестным, а n- эго порядковым номером, мне потом нужно будет ввесты выражение X(n+1), зарание спасибо!

Comment: Используйте одну и ту же переменную для текущего значения `X_n`. Ваша программная логика должна знать, с каким именно `X_n` код работает в данную минуту.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, если не терпится, то X[n], но VladD прав, такого плодить, как правило, не надо.